# Azure DevOps Taskboard: Can I drag anything besides Tasks?

Tags: azure-devops

[image]On the Azure DevOps TaskBoard for a sprint, it would appear that the only thing I can drag across the board is Tasks. Not bugs.  Not Backlog items.   Which means if I want to see where a bug is on the board, I have to create a task for it. (Note: My project uses Scrum.  Bugs are managed with requirements)

I guess this makes sense.  It is a "Task board" after all.  But this seems tedious.  Most of the time, the bug is the task.  I make a bug, make a check in, and mark it done.  I would expect to be able to drag the bug itself across the board to mark it done.

And even if I go to the trouble for creating a task for a bug (or a Backlog Item) and then I drag the task across the task board to "Done", the bug's status still stays where it was.  It doesn't change to not done.  I then have to go to the bug and manually mark it as "Done"

This really limits the usefulness of the Taskboard for our planning.

Am I missing something?  Is there way to change this?

Comment: Bugs are treated either as tasks or as requirements, depending on your board configuration. You can choose to have bugs treated as tasks, but then they'll have to be parented to a requirement, or they'll simply show up as "unparented." That may be the approach you want to take; using unparented bugs-as-tasks so that they show up on the task board.

Comment: I did try that.  You're right, it does let me drag bugs now, but unfortunately this setting now also prevents new bugs from showing up in the main Product Backlog for planning purposes ***unless*** I also remember to then assign the new bug to some parent Product Backlog Item (PBI)

So I go to Boards >> Backlog and choose my team's backlog and and  my new bugs aren't there.    And since this is the online version, I can't create a rule to force me to assign new bugs to PBIs

Comment: But I appreciate the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose to manage the Bugs with tasks as Daniel commented. And You can use extension [Work item form one click actions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mohitbagra.witoneclickactions) to assign the Bug to some parent PBI automatically. See below example:

First you need to install `Work item form one click actions` extension to your Organization.

Then Go to project setting page-->WIT One Click Actions under Extensions-->Bugs-->Create rule group-->New Rule

- Triggers: **New work item load**

[image]

- Actions: **Link to an existing work item**(**relation type**: Parent; **Work Item id**: Id of PBI)

[image]

After above rule is created. The newly created bugs will be automatically added to the parent PBI you specified in above rule.

However, The PBI and Bugs(managed with requirements) can be moved around in **Boards**. So you can use the **filter** to view your work items in a specific sprint.

[image]

Comment: This sounds Brilliant.  And like exactly what I need.  I will investigate this today

Comment: You can also drag Product Backlog Items on and off of sprints from the [Product Backlog Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/sprints/assign-work-sprint?view=azure-devops). I expected this to be on a board rather than the backlog (like GitLab), so I didn't find it before finding this help.